# symfony2 suddenly stricter on form labels

Tags: forms, label, symfony-2.3

So, in the horribly long list of issues following a symfony2 update from 2.0 up to 2.3, my form labels suddenly throw errors when they contain the swedish characters åäö, or spaces.

This is no longer allowed:

```
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Epost '))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password', 'first_name' => 'Nytt lösenord ', 'second_name' => 'Upprepa lösenord ',));
```

This works though:

```
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Epost '))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password', 'first_name' => 'Nytt_losenord', 'second_name' => 'Upprepa_losenord',));
```

That is of course unacceptable from a graphic design point of view, so is my only option now to specify each form field separatly in a twig template, just because åäö is no longer allowed as a label?

Comment: Which concrete error do you get?

Comment: The name "Lösenord" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/UPGRADE-2.1.md I found this

> Form and field names must now start with a letter, digit or underscore
>   and only contain letters, digits, underscores, hyphens and colons.

So I guess for the form type "repeated" that one usually use for passwords when you want that confirm box, the name_first and name_second are actually not labels but form field names, thus the restriction.

I ended up labeling mine in twig, guess that is the easiest way.